# Angular 2 pipe/filter with component variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

i have app that shows events from this and next week. Weeks are switched by two buttons. I need filter/pipe that will show only events from current active week. I had this filter in Angular 1 and everything was working but in An 2 I am not able to get this filter work. See code:

```
    @Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/lunches/lunches.html',
    providers: [LunchService, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
})

export class Lunches {
    weekDuration:number = 24 * 60 * 60 * 7 * 1000;
    timestampFix:number = 24 * 60 * 60 * 4 * 1000;

    currentWeekNumber:number = parseInt(new Date().getTime() / this.weekDuration);
    nextWeekNumber:number = this.currentWeekNumber + 1;
    activeWeekNumber:string = '2408';
    lunches:Array;
    activeLunches:Array;
    noData:boolean = true;

    constructor(private lunchService:LunchService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadLunches();
    }

    loadLunches() {
        this.lunchService.getLunchList().subscribe(
            data => {
                var lunches = data;
                lunches.forEach((item, index) => {
                    lunches[index].date = new Date(item.date);
                });
                this.lunches = lunches;
                this.weekFilter();
            }
        );
    }

    weekFilter() {
        var activeLunches = [];
        this.lunches.forEach((item, index) => {
            var lunchDate = new Date(item.date).getTime() - this.timestampFix;
            console.log(this.currentWeekNumber, ' = ', parseInt(lunchDate / this.weekDuration));
            if (this.activeWeekNumber == parseInt(lunchDate / this.weekDuration)) {
                this.noData = false;
                activeLunches.push(item);
            }
        });
        this.activeLunches = activeLunches;
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<div padding>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="activeWeekNumber" (click)="weekFilter()">
        <ion-segment-button value="{{currentWeekNumber}}" selected>
            This week
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="{{nextWeekNumber}}">
            Next
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
</div>
<ion-card *ngIf="noData">
    <ion-card-content>
        No lunches for this week.
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
<ion-card *ngFor="#lunch of activeLunches">
    <ion-card-header>
        <h2>{{lunch.date | date: "E d. M."}}</h2>
    </ion-card-header>
</ion-card>
```

That is my actual code that doesnt work well, and i think its bad solutions. I tried write that as pipe but i wasnt able to acces and change variable noData.

EDIT: Based on comments, i decide to use this solution, but there is problem how to trigger weekFilter function everytime when activeWeekVariable change. Any ideas?

Comment: Your approach doesn't look bad. What doesn't work?  If you need additional parameters to a pipe, just pass them in `*ngFor="#lunch of activeLunches | week:currentWeekNo:noData"`

Comment: Problem is i need modify that noData variable and work again with him in template, render error if nothing pass filter.

Comment: As mentioned, I don't see a strong reason for a pipe. If you change `noData` to an object you can manipulate it. `hasData = {value: false}` and then pass `hasData` to the pipe and bind to `*ngIf="hasData.value"`

Comment: I think the problem you are facing in your current code is that you are not resetting noData to true. I suggest you add 'this.noData = true' in the first line of weekFilter()

Comment: Ok, thanks, but if i wont use pipe, i will need to call weekFilter every time when activeWeekNumber changes, but i dont know how to that.

Comment: @DanielSuchý if you prefer using a pipe, check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OsYpMxn8jIWfwvzK2ZuH?p=preview), if it's not clear. I could explain it.

Comment: Thank! Looks nice too, i will try to use it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get notified when

```ts
activeWeekNumber:string = '2408';
```

changes there are different ways.

- You can change the field to a getter/setter

```ts
_activeWeekNumber:string = '2408';
get activeWeekNumber():string {
  return this._activeWeekNumber;
}
set activeWeekNumber(value:string) {
  this._activeWeekNumber = value;
}
```

- or use the event from ngModel

```ts
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="activeWeekNumber" (ngModelChange)="doSomething($event) (click)="weekFilter()"
```

Comment: Thanks! Works flawlessly :)